USB Printer ALWAYS BUSY (Error: claimInterface error: Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY)
I want to connect to printer and print barcodes from node using usb lib, but I get this error - Error: claimInterface error: Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY. I tried to use web/no web usb device - the same error. If I ask him isKernalDriverActive() he tells false, but libusb say it is busy! I don't know.
Before this error I was getting LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS and I solve it like this
text
If I use deviceInterface.detachKernelDriver() and then eviceInterface.attachKernelDriver() it throws another error - LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND.
I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
const usb = require('usb');

(async () => {
    const device = usb.findByIds(0x232b, 0x5e20);
    
    const webDevice = await usb.WebUSBDevice.createInstance(device);

    if (webDevice) {
        console.log(webDevice); // WebUSB device
    }

    await webDevice.open();
    await webDevice.selectConfiguration(1);
    await webDevice.claimInterface(0)
})();


From terminal command 'lsusb' I get
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 320f:5055 Evision RGB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 232b:5e20 Pantum Ltd. M6550NW series
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:19af ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



Printer model - Pantum M6550NW series

Have you installed the Linux driver? https://www.pantum.de/support/download/driver/

@Risto I did it right now, but it didn't solve the problem, thanks for your answer

And is the driver loaded? Have you checked it? Keyword dmesg

@Risto yes, there are no errors in 'dmesg'
